# Insert multiple objects using CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a situation where I want to pre populate a CoreData DB with a few entries.  As this is done at runtime as a few things are detected then I need to do this in code.

I have an issue with this code where it only inserts the second one....

```
Event *event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [event setLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:52.25]];
    [event setLon:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.75]];
    [event setLatspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.7]];
    [event setLonspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.88]];
    [event setName:@"Test, 1"];
    // Commit the change.
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }

    [event setLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:53.25]];
    [event setLon:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:56.75]];
    [event setLatspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.7]];
    [event setLonspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.88]];
    [event setName:@"Test 2"];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` only once, and use the same object twice. Thus only one item is being inserted, its existing attributes *modified*, then the changes to the same object saved.

You need to call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` again on the same `event` variable for each subsequent item, after saving it (the managed objects produced here are all autoreleased):

```
event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[event setLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:53.25]];
[event setLon:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:56.75]];
[event setLatspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.7]];
[event setLonspan:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.88]];
[event setName:@"Test 2"];

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```